# how to remove Duplicates in SQL without DISTINCT

Tags: ssms

I have this code below that is pulling duplicates on invoice #.

```
SELECT DISTINCT                     
 APVID [VENDOR ID],                  
 APINV [INVOICE #],
APEXDV [DIVISION],
 APEXLT [STORE #],
APEXAC [GL #],
APSTK# [STOCK #],
 APIDTE [INVOICE DATE],
 APCDTE [PAID DATE],
 APDSC [DESCRIPTION],
 APEX$$ [LINE AMOUNT],
APAMT [INVOICE AMOUNT],
appym [PAID AMOUNT],
APCHK [CHECK #],                          
 APITEM [BARCODE #],
APSEQ [Line item]
FROM  [AccountingDM].[dbo].[tblPpAPInv]               
WHERE APVID in ('DWI006', 'CV2829', 'dw 007', 'dwi001')
and apcdte between 20170101 and 20170331
```

Is there a way to make it just pull invoices once and not multiple?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only sure way is `SELECT DISTINCT APINV [INVOICE #] FROM ...`.  If that's too severe, you need to start eliminating columns from the select list which could be contributing to the duplication.  From what I can see, good candidates to consider for elimination would be `[DESCRIPTION]`, `[LINE AMOUNT]`, `[BARCODE #]`, and `[Line item]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` & `OFFSET` at the end of your query to only fetch one record. Depending on whether you need the most recent or oldest invoice or some other criteria, you can additionally `ORDER BY ASC|DESC`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT                     
   APVID [VENDOR ID],                  
   APINV [INVOICE #],
   APEXDV [DIVISION],
   APEXLT [STORE #],
   APEXAC [GL #],
   APSTK# [STOCK #],
   APIDTE [INVOICE DATE],
   APCDTE [PAID DATE],
   APDSC [DESCRIPTION],
   APEX$$ [LINE AMOUNT],
   APAMT [INVOICE AMOUNT],
   appym [PAID AMOUNT],
   APCHK [CHECK #],                          
   APITEM [BARCODE #],
   APSEQ [Line item]
 FROM  [AccountingDM].[dbo].[tblPpAPInv]               
   WHERE APVID in ('DWI006', 'CV2829', 'dw 007', 'dwi001')
      and apcdte between 20170101 and 20170331
 OFFSET 0 ROWS
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: I tried the fetch first row and it gave me an invalid usage of the option.

Comment: @AnthonyVillanova  Try with `OFFSET 0 ROWS` before the `FETCH` statement? see edit.